# Allow one random character at any position in string pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find a specific pattern in a string with the allowance of one (or a number I can set) tolerance deviation character at any position in the string.

So if I am looking for a date in the Format yyyy-mm-dd. Then I would like to accept for example:

'2020-08x-12'

'x2020-08-01'

'2020-08-x12'

So far I've got the Standard pattern recognition:

```
SELECT foo
FROM bar
WHERE foo LIKE '[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9][-][0-1][0-9][-][0-3][0-9]'
```

Now I would like to allow a random character in between (max 1 character) and still recognize the pattern.

Comment: You can't, at least not with `LIKE`, unless you fancy writing out individual patterns for every possibility. It has no provisions for matching optional characters other than `%`, which matches any number of them.

Comment: Is there any other option then, for example with PATINDEX that is relatively simple?

Comment: `PATINDEX` is no more powerful than `LIKE`. T-SQL's options for string matching are very limited.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server is not optimal for this but you can use a massive `OR` and `LIKE`:

```
WHERE foo LIKE '[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9][-][0-1][0-9][-][0-3][0-9]' OR
      foo LIKE '[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9][-][0-1][0-9][-][0-3][0-9]_' OR
      foo LIKE '[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9][-][0-1][0-9][-][0-3]_[0-9]' OR
      foo LIKE '[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9][-][0-1][0-9][-]_[0-3][0-9]' OR
      . . .
      foo LIKE '_[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9][-][0-1][0-9][-][0-3][0-9]'
```

The `_` matches exactly one character.  So the idea is to put it in the pattern at every possible position.

Hmmm . . . an alternative method that should work is to match with any "random" characters between the known ones and then check the length:

```
WHERE foo LIKE '%[1-2]%[0-9]%[0-9]%[0-9]%[-]%[0-1]%[0-9]%[-]%[0-3]%[0-9]%' AND
      LEN(foo) IN (10, 11)
```

Comment: ok the first one is not really an option unless I can use a loop which I know is not a good idea in SQL. The second one however I find interesting and will experiment with it a little.